# Giving DOM Nodes Javascript Functionality

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm working on a Single Page App and quite a few of the DOM node construction functions return a reference to the object they've created. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
if (!document.getElementById('playlistHeader')) {
        appView.buildKit.playlist.headerWrap();
    }

    // construct element
    var secondaryBtnsWrap = document.createElement("div");
    secondaryBtnsWrap.id = "playlistSecondaryBtnWrap";
    secondaryBtnsWrap.className = "clearright right";

    // attach it
    document.getElementById('playlistHeader').appendChild(secondaryBtnsWrap);

    // return reference to dom node
    return secondaryBtnsWrap;
```

I figured it would be redundant to destroy and recreate the node when changing between views, so I started working towards being able to wipe the content of some nodes (subsections of the site) by giving them a custom function that handles the wiping.

```
// build wipe function
    secondaryBtnsWrap.wipe = function(){

        // do custom wiping here
    }
```

The idea is to "reset" parts of the UI and rebuild the differences between the views. For example, if there was a button that we'd need regardless, the wipe function won't delete it. That way it eliminates the extra legwork of creating the same element.

In some cases it's a lot easier to get a reference to a node and trigger the custom function attached, but I was wondering if its actually a good idea or if it just SEEMS like a good idea (but isn't).

---

**TL;DR VERSION**

Is it a good idea to give DOM nodes Javascript functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM Nodes are first-class objects. Nothing wrong with assigning them your own properties. Just don't try to overwrite any built-ins (except perhaps event handlers, but you should really be using `attachEvent`/`addEventListener`). In my opinion, it's one of the most convenient features of javascript in terms of user-interface development.

You could also build your page with a standard object which generates its own DOM nodes. You can attach event listeners which invoke functions on said object for interactivity. Use closures to reference the owner object. For instance:

```
function Foo() {
    this.element = undefined;
    this.createTextbox();
}

Foo.prototype.createTextbox = function() {
    var $self = this;
    this.element = document.createElement('input');
    this.element.type = 'text';
    this.element.addEventListener('change', function() { 
        $self.onChange.apply($self, arguments); 
    });
}

Foo.prototype.onChange = function() {
    console.log(this.element.value);
}

Foo.prototype.Render = function(target) {
    target = target || document.body;
    target.appendChild(this.element);
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.Render();
```

Both methods are equally valid, but I'd say the latter is probably more convenient when either the design or functionality needs to be significantly modified (rather than changing ids, classes, and layouts in both places, you only have to change them in one).

Comment: Very clean and succinct. 
+1 for such an excellent answer and clean code. Quality stuff :)